# Comparing strings both are correct but executes else eitherway

Tags: string, jsp, if-statement, authentication

So I'm just messing around with JSP and attempted to make a login form, now when I enter "test" as username and "test" as password it is supposed to log in, as that account is created in the database. Instead of "logging in" it just shows me the text "Incorrect username: test" and then on a new line the database value that was returned from the method I wrote, which is "test".

Please help me with this question, it's really starting to bother me.

This is my code:

```
String userID = request.getParameter("username").trim();
String pass = request.getParameter("password").trim();

String corrUserID = MySQL.getString("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='" + userID + "'", "username").toString();
String corrPass = MySQL.getString("SELECT password FROM users WHERE username='" + pass + "'", "password").toString();

if(corrUserID != "String" && corrPass != "String" && userID != "Username" && pass != "Password"){
    if(userID == corrUserID){
        if(pass == corrPass){

            out.println("Logged in!");
            response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");

        }else{
            out.println("Incorrect password.");
        }
    }else{
        out.println("Incorrect username: " + userID + "<br/>" + corrUserID);
    }
}else{
    out.println("Please enter a valid username and password.");
}
```

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text.**

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Do not prevent users from having passwords with leading or trailing whitespace.

Comment: I wasn't going to, also this is just for fun and killing time, I'm not really being serious about working with JSP yet as I'm only working with it for about 3-4 days. As for your last comment, I see what you mean, good call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) to compare `String` .

```
if(userID.equals(corrUserID))
```

`==`tests for equality of references.

`.equals()` tests for equality of values.

Comment: Thank you! You saved me from giving up, I always thought .equals() did the same as ==, thanks for telling me. :)